# How can I change more than one attibute at the same time?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I'm working in QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour. I started by creating a shapefile from an AutoCAD file. The problem is that in the AutoCAD, my layers had symbols like: "~; ç; ^". As the QGIS does not support thess symbols, my attribute table is really confusing, so I want to rewrite those attributes.

What I mean is, in one column, I want to change more than one line.
My problem is that I have more than 100 of each I want to rewrite. I thought it could be a way of changing more than one at the same time.

Is it possible?

Comment: You should really try to figure out the correct encoding of the Shapefile. QGIS is really good in handling all kinds of encodings but you have to know which encoding was used by AutoCad.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with underdark. If you want to change more than one line into the same new attribute, use the QuickMultiAttributeEdit Plugin. But you really should check why you have problems with importing your data.

Comment: The problem in importing the data is because of the symbols isn't? QGIS does not accept these kind of symbols I think, at least for now I already have issues with that more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

How about exporting the shape-table to an txt or XML, find and replace those symbols with others. Then link the edited table with the shape-files table by an unique attribute? Then delete the "old" columns and replace with the new ones. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're up for using PostGRESQL, you could use regexp_replace(string text, pattern text, replacement text [, flags text]).  This will allow you to identify all of the text you want to change, as well as give it a new character that you would rather see.  You can do all of your lines without ever having to see a single one (as long as you are confident in your results).   Documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html